# htaccess redirect append query string?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, query-string

I have an htaccess redirect that needs to forward the query string to the new URL, but it's getting dropped after the redirect. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

```
RewriteRule ^services/agents.*$          https://services.example.com/agents/ [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2):

The same rule is working fine on my server. The problem should be something else.
I added the same rule on my server and I get the following redirect

```
http://mysite.com/services/agents/foo?foo=bar => https://services.mysite.com/agents/?foo=bar
```

Please note that you don't need to add the QSA flag since the target doesn't include any query string.
[This article](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/) might contain some useful information to help you dealing with Htaccess and Query String.

Comment: I figured it out. The server I was redirecting to had its own redirect set up for /agents/ => /services/agents. Sigh..

Answer (score 2):

In general there is no need to explicitly append the query or use the QSA flag if you don’t specify a query for the substitution. But as you said your rule doesn’t work, try this:

```
RewriteRule ^services/agents.*$ https://services.example.com/agents/?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```